# jQuery - Text replace on string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code which check all the checkboxes and add or remove checked status (this part is working). I need to change text when this function is clicked from "Select All" to "De-select All".
Button to select all:

```
<a class="zute_strane_izmena_selektuj_sve">Select All</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
var selektuj_sve = $('.zute_strane_izmena_selektuj_sve'),
slike = $('.zuta_strana_trenutne_slike'),
box = slike.find(':checkbox');

selektuj_sve.on('click', function(){
    box.attr('checked', !box.is(':checked'));
});
```

What I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
selektuj_sve.on('click', function() {
    $(this).text(box.is(':checked') ? 'Deselect All' : 'Select All');
    box.attr('checked', !box.is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

trt this:

```
selektuj_sve.on('click', function(){
    box.attr('checked', !box.is(':checked'));
    $(this).html('De-select All'); // u can use text() instead of html().. this changes the  text inside to  deselectAll...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selektuj_sve.on('click', function(){
    box.attr('checked', !box.is(':checked'));
    $(this).text('De-select All');
});
```